# Plot PAM Cluster results with fviz_clust

Tags: r, plot, cluster-analysis

My data set has got 821.000 rows and 18 columns. The variables are continous. As there are some dummy variables I selected only the continous columns. I used pam cluster algorithm and a dissmiliarity matrix. While trying to plot the cluster results an error came up.

```
structure(list(X = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 11L, 15L, 16L, 

821037L, 821038L, 821039L, 821040L, 821041L, 821042L, 821043L, 

821044L, 821047L, 821048L), BASKETS_NZ = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 

1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 

LOGONS = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 

0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), PIS = c(71L, 39L, 50L, 4L, 

13L, 4L, 13L, 23L, 8L, 7L, 24L, 3L, 111L, 33L, 3L, 46L, 11L, 

8L, 65L, 15L), PIS_AP = c(14L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 

0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 13L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), PIS_DV = c(3L, 

19L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 38L, 8L, 0L, 

5L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 2L), PIS_PL = c(0L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 

11L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 32L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PIS_SDV = c(18L, 

0L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 

13L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), PIS_SHOPS = c(3L, 24L, 13L, 3L, 0L, 

0L, 2L, 17L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 1L, 71L, 16L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 0L, 3L, 

2L), PIS_SR = c(19L, 0L, 14L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 

11L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 20L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), QUANTITY = c(13L, 

2L, 18L, 1L, 14L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 

4L, 1L, 3L, 17L, 8L), WKA = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 

1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), NEW_CUST = c(0L, 

0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 

0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), EXIST_CUST = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 

1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), WEB_CUST = c(1L, 

0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 

0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), MOBILE_CUST = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 

0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), 

TABLET_CUST = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 

0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), LOGON_CUST_STEP2 = c(0L, 

0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 

0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 

11L, 15L, 16L, 821037L, 821038L, 821039L, 821040L, 821041L, 821042L, 

821043L, 821044L, 821047L, 821048L), class = "data.frame")
```

## Code

```
WKA_ohneJB <- read.csv("WKA_ohneJB_PCA.csv", header=TRUE, sep = ";", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Baur_WKA <- subset(WKA_ohneJB, WKA == 1)

Baur_WKA_scale <- scale (Baur_WKA[c(2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)])

set.seed (123)

sample <- Baur_WKA_scale[sample(nrow(Baur_WKA_scale), 10000), ]

dist.eucl <- dist(sample, method = "euclidean")

pam.res <- pam(dist.eucl, 3, metric = "euclidean", stand = FALSE)

fviz_cluster(pam.res, palette = c("#00AFBB", "#FC4E07", "#9932CC"), # color palette 
          ellipse.type = "t", # Concentration ellipse
          repel = FALSE, # Avoid label overplotting (slow) 
          ggtheme = theme_classic() )
```

> Error: Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x),  : 
>     'data' must be of type vector, was 'NULL

Comment: Look at `str(WKA_onheJB)`. It appears that the first column is labeled `X` and consists of rownames. The `scale` function converts these to `NaN`s.

Comment: @ dcarlson thank you.